# How to holds on celery tasks until the database transaction is committed

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, celery

I have a simple context manager with transaction:

```
@contextmanager
def transaction(db):
    try:
        yield
        db.session.commit()
    except:
        db.session.rollback()
        raise
```

And I have code with tasks:

```
with transaction(db):
    for x in Test.query.all()
        x.update()
        notify_change.apply_async()
```

How to holds on tasks until session commit or abort tasks? Monkey patching ? any ideas ?

How to implement something similar to `django-celery-transactions` ??

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example from someone dealing with the same issue:

https://medium.com/hypertrack/dealing-with-database-transactions-in-django-celery-eac351d52f5f

The essence is that you should somehow save all of your `apply_async()` calls until you know your database transaction has ended.